# Add ssh fingerprint to known_hosts without actually ssh'ing into machine

Tags: ssh

I am setting up a multi-node hadoop cluster. As a part of this process I need to have all the nodes be able to ssh into each other (this is needed for other parts of the hadoop ecosystem).

I end up having to ssh into each node, then exit, then ssh into the next one, then exit, etc. Then repeat this on each node. Is there a way to do this faster?

Right now I am doing `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 127.0.0.1` which is better than having to type `yes` every time, but not ideal.

I'd prefer something like:

```
[command] localhost
[command] 127.0.0.1
[command] 0.0.0.0
```

That way I could just throw all the IP's in a script and run the script on every node and save myself a huge chunk of time and tedium.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite the trend of answering my own questions -

Here's something that works for me: I found you can pass commands with `ssh` in the format

```
ssh $host 'command1; command2; command3'
```

so I am just passing

```
ssh $host 'exit'
```